# XCode Error: No provisioned iOS devices are available with a compatible iOS version

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning

I know this question has been asked quite a bit before, but none of the known causes seem to be the case in my situation.

- The device is provisioned & connected. I can see it in iTunes as well as the XCode organizer and it's marked 'green'.
- It is also set up for development and has the provisioning profile used for development installed. The profile is also present and valid in the XCode organizer.
- The project & target 'iOS Deployment Target' is definitely below that of the device (deployment target iOS 3.0, device is 6.0).
- The device is added to the development provisioning profile in the apple dev site.

Any idea what else could be causing this problem? I should add that my XCode version is 4.6.3.

Comment: Is the minimum iOS version of the app = or below the version of the device?  And maximum iOS version = or above?

Comment: Did you change the app bundle identifier to match the one you registered under while creating app id in app dev site?

Comment: If by minimum iOS version we are talking about the deployment target, then yes that's 3.0 < 6.0, and if by maximum iOS version we mean the base sdk, then yes, that's 6.1 > 6.0.

Comment: And the app bundle identifier does in fact match the app id on the developer site.

Comment: Do you see the provisioning profile of the target listed when you're looking at Organizer -> [device name] -> Prov Profiles. While I understand you said the Prov Profile itself is valid you don't indicate if you were looking at your global Prov Profiles or which are valid for the device.

Comment: Yep, the provisioning profile is both under the 'Library' section and under the device's provisioning profiles - and marked valid in both.

Comment: just curious, have you tried the refresh button in the organizer?

Comment: @Mobiletainment many times :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question here. Wasted a bunch of time on this, but sometimes it's the simplest thing that kills you. It turns out someone on my team had changed the target's supported Device (under Targets -> APP_TARGET -> Summary -> Devices in the project settings) to 'iPad', when the app was supposed to be 'Universal' all along, and I was trying to deploy to an iPhone.